# Drupal SMTP Module won't enable

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, smtp, drupal-modules

I am attempting to setup SMTP on my Drupal installation but I am having trouble even enabling the module.

I have manually installed the module to /sites/all/modules/smtp and it is displaying correctly in the modules manager via the admin dashboard. However when I check the enable box and refresh the page the module is still not enabled...

Why is this module not enabling after checking the 'enabled' box on the module manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File permissions must be set tup 755 to write/enable modules I guess. I set my file permissions to 755 temporarily and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

got to configuration >> system >> smtp and there on the top you will find the on and off option button to activate it. when you choose on then your smtp will start working. Even after that you need to set the port and other options in that.